# Restricting a continuous positive-semidefinite function to a finite subset

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, matrix-analysis, positivity

The following is a toy version of something I've been fiddling with and I thought it might be more efficient to post it as a question here.

Just to fix definitions: for me, a complex-valued function $f$ on a group $G$ is said to be *positive-semi-definite* if, for every choice of points $x_1, \dots, x_n\in G$, the $n\times n$ matrix $[f(x_i^{-1}x_j)]_{i,j=1}^n$ is PSD in the usual sense. Note that in this definition I do not assume $G$ is countable, nor do I assume $f$ is continuous.

**Question 1.** Let $f$ be a continuous PSD function on $\mathbb R$, and pick a finite subset $F\subset R$; then let $E=\{-x+y \mid x,y \in F\}$. Does there always exist a PSD function $h$ on $\mathbb R$, *with finite or countably infinite support*,such that $h\vert_E = f\vert_E$ ?

Obviously, if we knew that the ``truncation'' of $f$ to the set $E$ was itself a PSD function on $\mathbb R$, then the answer to Q1 would be positive. But I don't see why this truncated function would always be PSD.

**Question 2.** The analogue of Q1 with $\mathbb R$ replaced by $\mathbb R^d$ for $d\geq 2$.

My personal suspicion is that Q2 will have a negative answer but this is based on pessimism rather than any genuine intuition.

Comment: Just to clarify: $x^{-1}y$ in the definition of $E$ is done in the group $(\mathbb R,+)$, so it's a fancy way of writing $y-x$ ?

Comment: @ChristianRemling That's correct. I've edited the notation to remove the ambiguity/confusion

Comment: As to "countably infinite" support, why don't you just take the restriction of $f$ to $\text{span}_{\mathbb Q}F$?

Comment: @fedja I thought very briefly about that. Let's denote that span by $T$ and denote your suggested restriction by $h$. Now I choose $x_1, x_2 \in T$ and $x_3,x_4 \in \mathbb R \setminus T$. So the $4\times 4$ matrix I get from $h$ agrees in the NW $2\times 2$ block with the corresponding matrix I get from $f$. I guess it is zero in the NE $2\times 2$ block because $T+({\mathbb R}\setminus T)\subseteq {\mathbb R}\setminus T$, and by symmetry its zero in the SW block. But why do I have control in the SE block?

Comment: Because $0=x_3-x_3=x_4-x_4\in T$ and $x_2-x_3$ is either in $T$, in which case you are fine, or not in $T$, in which case the corresponding element is $0$. In general, the matrix splits into blocks corresponding to cosets of $\mathbb R/T$ and each coset is as good as $T$ itself. Am I missing something?

Comment: @fedja you miss nothing. For $H<G$ subgroup, the extension by 0 of a PD function on $H$ is a PD on $G$. From representation theoretic pov this corresponds to induction. In particular the answer to Q3 (general $G$) is positive.

Comment: @fedja This seems to work, thanks! I can only assume that when I first did this calculation in my head I made a silly error. The coset description of the partition makes it clear that this will work on any locally compact group (as Uri has said, although I don't quite follow his sketch). If you wrote up your comments as an answer I'd be happy to accept

Comment: @UriBader I can see how Fedja's sketch generalizes to arbitrary $G$. I don't quite follow how this can be deduced from induction of reps, although it looks plausible. You talk of extending a PD function on H by declaring it to be zero outside H, but isn't my question the converse? I have a PD function on G and I want to know that setting it to be zero outside H still gives me something PD

Comment: Yemon, the two operations $PD(G)\to PD(H)$ and $PD(H)\to PD(G)$ given by "restriction" and "extending by 0" correspond to the functors "Restriction" and "Induction" on (cyclic) unireps of the (abstract) groups $G$ and $H$. Thus, from RT pov, the answer to your question is "restrict to a countable group containing $F$ and induce back to $G$". Practically this is the same as "restrict $f$ to a countable group containing $F$ and extend by 0" which @fedja gave. I'd be happy to explain further in case the correspondence (or anything else) is still unclear.

Comment: @UriBader Sorry for the delay in responding, I went and did my homework and I agree with you and fedja. In fact, it turns out this procedure (extend by setting the function to be 0 outside H) is already in Rieffel's original paper on induction for representations of Cstar algebras, which I guess I should have read more carefully when I was first learning these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for *countably infinite* has been given by fedja and Uri Bader in the comments and is yes: put $f$ to $0$ outside of the subgroup generated by $E$, and leave $f$ unchanged on this subgroup.

For *finite*, the answer is no. For an example, take $f=1$ and $E=\{-1,0,1\}$. Since the only PSD function of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & a \\ 1&1&1\\ b &1 &1\end{pmatrix}$ is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1&1&1\\ 1 &1 &1\end{pmatrix}$, we have that any positive-semidefinite function whose restriction to $E$ is $1$ has to be constant equal to $1$ on $\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Nice! I wonder if this example can be seen as some kind of argument with multiplicative domains or the Schwarz inequality for cp maps... but this is purely idle speculation

Comment: @YemonChoi: sure. $f \colon G \to \mathbf{C}$ being PSD means that the Fourier multiplier $M_f$ with symbol $f$ is completely positive. So if we have such PSD $f$ and $t \in G$ such that $f(t) = f(0)=1$, we have (Choi) that $t$ belongs to the multiplicative domain of $M_f$, and so the whole group generated by $f$ belongs to the multiplicative domain, ie that $f$ is constant equal to $1$ on the group generated by $t$.

Comment: I often feel that Choi (Y) needs to pay closer attention to ideas introduced by Choi (M-D)

Comment: I have often wondered: is there any connection between you and Choi (M-D)?

Comment: Not that I know of...